# using Function Keys on a windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown, keyup

The requirement is for a user to enter a number in a textbox and if they press F5 the code does something with the value in the textbox. I have set the form's this.KeyPreview = true; When user hits F5 the keyup event fires and processes correctly, BUT now every time I enter a character in the textbox the keyup event also fires. Is there a way to turn this off? or is it just something I have to deal with in debugging? If I don't have breakpoint there it's fine, but do I want that event to fire for every character?

Comment: Its KeyUp not F5KeyUp so yeah you get it everytime for any captured keycode.

Comment: If you test for the key that interests you and put a breakpoint *within* the block that executes when that key is pressed, you don't have to deal with the other key presses.

Comment: ok, thanks! - yeah I ended up putting my breakpoints inside the case statement. Just wanted to make sure it was normal behavior and not something that would unecessarily cause performance issues

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the textbox event [Keyup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keyup?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

In the event handler check the KeyCode. If it equals `Keys.F5` do what you want to do when F5 is pressed. Also inform the system that you handled the event. In all other cases do what you want to do if F5 is not pressed.

```
private void OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F5)
    {
        this.HandleF5();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // not F5
        ...
    }
}

private void HandleF5()
{
    // On F5 clear the textbox and sound a beep
    this.textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
}
```

Consider to also check properties `Alt` and `Control` if you want to do simething different on `Alt-F5` / `Ctrl-F5`.